# How to use the logstash mutate or ruby filter

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, logstash

I have the following Json syntax

```
{"result": {
    "entities": {
        "SERVICE-CCC89FB0A922657A": "service1",
        "SERVICE-D279F46CD751424F": "service2",
        "SERVICE-7AB760E70FCDCA18": "service3",
    },
    "dataPoints": {
        "SERVICE-CCC89FB0A922657A": [
            [
                1489734240000,
                1101.0
            ],
            [
                1489734300000,
                null
            ]
        ],
        "SERVICE-7AB760E70FCDCA18": [
            [
                1489734240000,
                4080800.5470588235
            ],
            [
                1489734300000,
                null
            ]
        ],
        "SERVICE-D279F46CD751424F": [
            [
                1489734240000,
                26677.695652173912
            ],
            [
                1489734300000,
                null
            ]
        ]
    }
},
"@timestamp": "2017-03-17T07:05:37.531Z",
"data": "data",
"@version": "1"
}
```

I want to change the following and input it in elasticsearch.

```
{"@timestamp": "2017-03-17T07:05:37.531Z",
"data": "data",
"@version": "1",
    "data" : {
        "service1",: [
            [
                1489734240000,
                1101.0
            ],
            [
                1489734300000,
                null
            ]
        ],
        "service3" : [
            [
                1489734240000,
                4080800.5470588235
            ],
            [
                1489734300000,
                null
            ]
        ],
        "service2": [
            [
                1489734240000,
                26677.695652173912
            ],
            [
                1489734300000,
                null
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

This is the contents of the current logstash conf file.

```
input {
    http_poller {
        urls => {
            test => {
                method => get
                url => "https://xxxx.com"
                headers => {
                    Accept => "application/json"
                }
            }
        }
        request_timeout => 60
        schedule => { every => "60s" }
        codec => "plain"
    }
}

filter {
    json{
        source => "message"
        remove_field => ["[result][aggregationType]","message"]
    }

#    translate{
#    }

#    mutate{
#    }

#    ruby{
#    }

}

output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug {
        #metadata => true
        }
    }
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["http://192.168.0.36:9200"]
    }
}
```

I have just used elasticsearch and I do not know how to implement what filter to use.
I wonder if it is possible to implement the contents of the mutate filter rename.
Or should I implement code with ruby ​​filters?

It is likely that the entities will be arrayed with the ruby ​​filter to match the SERVICE- * s of the dataPoints.
However, it is difficult to cope with Ruby code.

I want you to help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Here are couple of filters are used for logstash...

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html

Comment: Thank you for replies to the question.

I looked up the logstash filter document page several times to find the answer I wanted, and I did dozens of searches on Google, but I found it difficult to find the answer I wanted.

The document page has only basic usage, so it is not easy to implement the functionality I want.